# Keras neural network function approximation

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm trying to approximate following function:
[image]

but my best result looks like:

[image]
(loss function on the right)
I've tried even with 50k epochs, similar results.

Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=1,kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,input_dim=1, activation=activation_fun))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape', 'cosine'])
history = model.fit(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=5000, verbose=0)

preds = model.predict(x_test)
prettyPlot(x,y,x_test,preds,history,'linear',5000)
model.summary()
```

**prettyPlot** function creates plots.

How can I achieve better results without changing the topology of the NN? I don't want it to be big or wide. I want to use even less hidden layers and neurons, if possible.

The function that I want to approximate:

```
def fun(X):
    return math.sin(1.2*X + 0.5) + math.cos(2.5*X + 0.2) + math.atan(2*X + 1) -  math.cos(2*X + 0.5)
```

samples:

```
range = 20
x = np.arange(0, range, 0.01).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array(list(map(fun, x))).reshape(-1,1)

x_test = (np.random.rand(range*10)*range).reshape(-1,1)
y_test = np.array(list(map(fun, x_test))).reshape(-1,1)
```

Then y and y_test are normalized using MinMaxScaler.

```
scalerY= MinMaxScaler((0,1))
scalerY.fit(y)
scalerY.fit(y_test)
y = scalerY.transform(y)
y_test = scalerY.transform(y_test)
```

Activation function in the last layer is linear.

Comment: What is `activation_fun` in the last layer?

Comment: Further, please add the code where you normalize `y` and `y_test`.

Comment: @today I added code. Activation fun in the last layer is linear.

Comment: I've also tried with sigmoid as a activation_fun in the last layer, similar results.

Comment: Well, first don't normalize `y` and `y_test`. It does not make sense at all since you want to approximate the function `fun` (so you need to preserve the real values; not to mention that such normalization by scaling completely distort the values). Second, if you want to normalize something it should be `x` and `x_test`. Third, modify the learning rate of optimizer (i.e. `keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)`) or try a different optimizer like `RMSprop`. Fourth, it is best practice to add a validation data to make sure you are not over-fitting. Let me know if any of these does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have problems with the accuracy try using a lot of data points like 10k-100k.

Comment: I don't think more data points will help, they wouldn't provide any new information. It will just increase computation time. I think around 200 data points are enough to capture the entirety of the information needed to replicate his function. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse me, I am a complete novice in this field and only started looking into AI models around 2-3 days ago
However I attempted to solve the above problem on my computer as well and I think OP's model has a few issues

- the first layer of the model suffers from "dying ReLU" problem, and replacing it with a LeakyReLU fixes it
- the next two hidden relu layers are not needed as I do not see what they would accomplish. Unlike the, first relu layer will discriminate between each of the hills and valleys in the graph and route the input to the appropriate neuron in the next layer
- next layer can just be a tanh layer that can reasonabily approximate a hill or a valley due to its shape
- I counted around 18 hills and valleys in the function we're trying to fit, so first layer could probably get away with 18 neurons/units. But in my tests around 20 give ok results, and 30 give enough leeway for perfect results in a reasonable time.
- That gives this model:

> ```
> epochs = 16000
> bs = 200
>
> model = tf.keras.Sequential([
>     tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=1),
>     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=30, kernel_initializer="random_uniform"),  
>     tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.15),
>     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=30, activation="tanh"),
>     
>     tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
> ])
>
> opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=.001, momentum=0.9)
> model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error')
>
> es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", mode="min", verbose=1, patience=5000, min_delta=0.0001, baseline=None)
> cblist = [es]
> model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=epochs, batch_size=bs, callbacks=cblist)
>
> fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 3))
> ax.plot(in1, out1, color="green")
> ax.plot(in1, preds, color="red")
> fig.tight_layout()
> plt.show(block=True)
> ```

in1 and out2 are using OPs function we're trying to match, with 200 data sample. in1 contains 200 data points, from 0 to 20, in 0.1 increments

I found a batch size of 32 like OP uses yields a too unstable loss value, and just batching the whole data set into one go (basically one batch per epoch) yielded better results. An almost perfect match, loss 0.082:

[image]

I hope this helps, and if I'm wrong in any of my statements, please do tell me, I'm new at this and eager to learn.

Comment: Would be good to know why this answer was downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Has identical task, you shoud use "tanh" activation function on output layer (or use only one layer with it)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).